# How to always run a specific program as administrator on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I use BSplayer and would like to know how to always run it as admin to prevent the annoying prompt. Creating a shortcut and running as admin is not viable since I use different media files each time to activate BSplayer

Answer (score 4):

From [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431742.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

1. On the Start menu, locate the program that you want to always run as an administrator.
2. Right-click the application’s shortcut, and then click *Properties*.
3. In the *Properties* dialog box, click the *Compatibility* tab.
4. Do one of the following:

   - To apply the setting to the currently logged-on user, select the *Run This Program As An Administrator* check box, and then click *OK*.
   - To apply the setting to all users on the computer and regardless of which shortcut is used to start the application, click *Change Setting For All Users* to display the *Properties* dialog box for the application’s `.exe` file, select the *Run This Program As An Administrator* check box, and then click *OK* twice.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I did as you told and there is still a prompt asking for privilege.

Comment: Might you be referring to the UAC (User Account Support)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control